# Convert 'Apr 26 2014' to '2014-04-26' in grails

Tags: java, grails-2.0

How can i use SimpleDateFormat() to convert  Apr 26 2014 to '2014-04-26' in grails ?
Or is there any other method ?
I have this

```
def fromDate = params.from_date;
```

which is 'Apr 26 2014'

Comment: Read the javadoc of SimpleDateFormat, and try something.

Comment: Would be good to know the purpose of your question as well. You might not need SimpleDateFormat, unless you want to represent the date as a string in a view. If you want to store a Date in the Database, for example, there are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The date should be formatted at its displayal, in the view, which means you can use `g:formatDate` tag for this purpose: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Tags/formatDate.html

Comment: for my purpose it is coming from datepicker and so cant be format in views

Comment: Here you'll find the best & official information for a best start, good luck: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html